# How to reset a dropdown list in jquery so nothing is selected?

Tags: jquery

I have this drop down list in a modal

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="selectInsert01">Country Name:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="selectInsert01" class="input-xlarge with-search" data-bind="foreach: citiesModel.countriesList">
            <option data-bind="text: Name, value: CountryID"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every time I select something and exit the modal and than open it again the selected value in the dropdown list is still selected. How do I reset the values so nothing is selected when I exit the modal

Comment: Show us your modal script code.

Answer (score 22):

On modal close

```
$("#selectInsert01 option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true); //set option of index 0 to selected
```

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me. Hope it helps.

```
$("#selectInsert01 option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have used bootstrap class selectpicker in your drop-down list:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', '-1');
```

You can also refer this link: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/03/how-to-reset-dropdown-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your dropdown as

```
$("#selectInsert01 option:first").attr("selected", true);
```

But it will only change the selected value of dropdown but not the label that is visible to user so you have to change that also. For that you can do :

```
$(".control-label").text($("#selectInsert01 option:first").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a placeholder you can do:

```
$("#selectBox").val($("#selectBox option:first").val());
```

Or even simpler if your placeholder does not hold a value:

```
$("#selectBox").val(0);
```